# Package libxul not found - Kiwix Wikpedia in Ubuntu Precise 12.04

Tags: 12.04

I'm trying to install the service Kiwix but I need a library that is not available for Ubuntu 12.04 LTS Precise leave the log and if someone could tell me how to install Seller would appreciate.

```
kiwix-0.9# ls
aclocal.m4  COMPILE       config.sub    COPYING  install-sh                                      ltmain.sh    missing  static
AUTHORS     config.guess  configure     depcomp  kiwix                                           Makefile.am  README
CHANGELOG   config.log    configure.ac  desktop  libxul-dev_1.8.1.16+nobinonly-0ubuntu1_all.deb  Makefile.in  src

kiwix-0.9# ./configure 
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... mawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles... no
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking for style of include used by make... GNU
checking dependency style of gcc... gcc3
checking for g++... g++
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes
checking whether g++ accepts -g... yes
checking dependency style of g++... gcc3
checking for g++... g++
checking for cl... no
checking for cl... no
checking for Xcode... no
checking for jar... jar
checking build system type... i686-pc-linux-gnu
checking host system type... i686-pc-linux-gnu
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /bin/sed
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking for fgrep... /bin/grep -F
checking for ld used by gcc... /usr/bin/ld
checking if the linker (/usr/bin/ld) is GNU ld... yes
checking for BSD- or MS-compatible name lister (nm)... /usr/bin/nm -B
checking the name lister (/usr/bin/nm -B) interface... BSD nm
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking the maximum length of command line arguments... 1572864
checking whether the shell understands some XSI constructs... yes
checking whether the shell understands "+="... yes
checking for /usr/bin/ld option to reload object files... -r
checking for objdump... objdump
checking how to recognize dependent libraries... pass_all
checking for ar... ar
checking for strip... strip
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking command to parse /usr/bin/nm -B output from gcc object... ok
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking for dlfcn.h... yes
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... (cached) yes
checking whether g++ accepts -g... (cached) yes
checking dependency style of g++... (cached) gcc3
checking how to run the C++ preprocessor... g++ -E
checking for objdir... .libs
checking if gcc supports -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions... no
checking for gcc option to produce PIC... -fPIC -DPIC
checking if gcc PIC flag -fPIC -DPIC works... yes
checking if gcc static flag -static works... yes
checking if gcc supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking if gcc supports -c -o file.o... (cached) yes
checking whether the gcc linker (/usr/bin/ld) supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether -lc should be explicitly linked in... no
checking dynamic linker characteristics... GNU/Linux ld.so
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking whether stripping libraries is possible... yes
checking if libtool supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build static libraries... yes
checking for ld used by g++... /usr/bin/ld
checking if the linker (/usr/bin/ld) is GNU ld... yes
checking whether the g++ linker (/usr/bin/ld) supports shared libraries... yes
checking for g++ option to produce PIC... -fPIC -DPIC
checking if g++ PIC flag -fPIC -DPIC works... yes
checking if g++ static flag -static works... yes
checking if g++ supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking if g++ supports -c -o file.o... (cached) yes
checking whether the g++ linker (/usr/bin/ld) supports shared libraries... yes
checking dynamic linker characteristics... GNU/Linux ld.so
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking for ranlib... (cached) ranlib
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... (cached) yes
checking for pkg-config... pkg-config
checking for perl... perl
checking fcntl.h usability... yes
checking fcntl.h presence... yes
checking for fcntl.h... yes
checking float.h usability... yes
checking float.h presence... yes
checking for float.h... yes
checking libintl.h usability... yes
checking libintl.h presence... yes
checking for libintl.h... yes
checking limits.h usability... yes
checking limits.h presence... yes
checking for limits.h... yes
checking stddef.h usability... yes
checking stddef.h presence... yes
checking for stddef.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... (cached) yes
checking for stdlib.h... (cached) yes
checking for string.h... (cached) yes
checking for strings.h... (cached) yes
checking sys/socket.h usability... yes
checking sys/socket.h presence... yes
checking for sys/socket.h... yes
checking sys/time.h usability... yes
checking sys/time.h presence... yes
checking for sys/time.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... (cached) yes
checking wchar.h usability... yes
checking wchar.h presence... yes
checking for wchar.h... yes
checking for stdbool.h that conforms to C99... yes
checking for _Bool... no
checking for inline... inline
checking for int16_t... yes
checking for int32_t... yes
checking for int64_t... yes
checking for int8_t... yes
checking for off_t... yes
checking for pid_t... yes
checking for size_t... yes
checking for uint16_t... yes
checking for uint32_t... yes
checking for uint64_t... yes
checking for uint8_t... yes
checking for ptrdiff_t... yes
checking vfork.h usability... no
checking vfork.h presence... no
checking for vfork.h... no
checking for fork... yes
checking for vfork... yes
checking for working fork... yes
checking for working vfork... (cached) yes
checking for stdlib.h... (cached) yes
checking for GNU libc compatible malloc... yes
checking for working strtod... yes
checking for getcwd... yes
checking for gettimeofday... yes
checking for memmove... yes
checking for memset... yes
checking for pow... yes
checking for regcomp... yes
checking for sqrt... yes
checking for strcasecmp... yes
checking for strchr... yes
checking for strdup... yes
checking for strerror... yes
checking for strtol... yes
Package libxul was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libxul.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'libxul' found
Package libxul was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libxul.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'libxul' found
checking for /stable... no
checking for "/nsISupports.idl"... no
configure: error: unable to find nsISupports.idl

kiwix-0.9# apt-get install libxul
Leyendo lista de paquetes... Hecho
Creando árbol de dependencias       
Leyendo la información de estado... Hecho
E: No se ha podido localizar el paquete libxul
```

Comment: Seems that `libxul` has been removed from the repositories. Did you try the static build from the Kiwix website? Or do you need to compile it from source?

Comment: Maybe installing `firefox-dev` helps. At least it contains `nsISupports.idl`.

Answer (score 0):

I already tested the distributed packages they old.

- Dynamic/Static pre-builds, get segmentation fault.
- Source v0.9, unmet dependencies in 14.04/16.04.

Only static build from github source did work, it downloads & compiles all needed libraries. 
(I didn't try dynamic build, because I don't want to track the dependencies myself)

1. Download source

   ```
   git clone https://github.com/kiwix/kiwix.git
   cd kiwix/
   ```
2. Install the missing libraries

   ```
   sudo apt-get install uuid-dev
   ```
3. Follow step as explained in the README file

   > ```
   > === Static (Probably what you need to do if you don't know) ===
   >
   > Kiwix uses shared libraries only. A static build of Kiwix is a build
   > which packages the dependencies. Command line tools (indexer, server,
   > etc) are compiled statically.
   >
   > # Run automake
   > ./autogen.sh
   >
   > # Run autoconf
   > ./configure --enable-compileall --enable-staticbins --disable-android
   >
   > # Download all dependencies
   > cd src/dependencies; make ; cd ../..
   >
   > # Reconfigure with dependencies (Gecko version)
   > ./configure --enable-compileall --enable-staticbins --disable-android
   >
   > # Compile
   > make
   >
   > # Creates tarbal suitable for distribution (no deps)
   > make diststatic
   >
   > # If you want to be able to run directly from your dev repository copy
   > # the "xulrunner" directory in the distributation tarball to the
   > # "kiwix" sub-directory of your developement tree.
   >
   > # Don't try to install with "make install", if you want to have kiwix
   > # install on your system just copy the directory in a /usr/local/bin
   > # directory.
   > ```

You should find the result `kiwix-0.*-static-*.tar.bz2` archive at the top folder.