# Installing Kiwix in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: software-installation

I downloaded the .zim file of wikipedia for Kiwix and being a complete novice and newbie to Ubuntu, have no idea as to the installation of the real Kiwix program.

I searched the questions in askubuntu which came up but none of them had anything which I could decipher.

I understand that we have to go to the 'kiwix-0.9' folder and then type './configure'.
But I got multiple errors.``

```
Package libxul was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libxul.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'libxul' found
configure: WARNING: unable to determine Gecko SDK version
checking for Gecko version... 0
configure: WARNING: unable to find nsISupports.idl
checking for xpidl... no
checking for python... /usr/bin/python
configure: WARNING: unable to find either the xpidl binary or the         typelib.py or header.py scripts in '/home/famubu/Desktop/kiwix-    0.9/src/dependencies/xulrunner-sdk/bin' directory.
checking zlib.h usability... no
checking zlib.h presence... no
checking for zlib.h... no
configure: error: cannot find zlib header
```

This is the part which says error.

Can someone help me fix this?

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: See if the answer here could work for you https://askubuntu.com/questions/229668/package-libxul-not-found-kiwix-wikpedia-in-ubuntu-precise-12-04

Comment: @That question was sth different.

Answer (score 1):

I had some problems extracting Kiwix files but finally figured out that NTFS file system simply didn't allow for proper extracting. It worked on ext4 for me. Other than that, to install Kiwix try this:

1. Go to https://www.kiwix.org/en/downloads/kiwix-reader/
Assuming you need 64 bit version, click on "KIWIX Reader for GNU/Linux – 64 bit binaries" to download compressed file (kiwix-0.9-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2)

2. Right click on the file and extract (MAKE SURE THE TARGET FOLDER IS LOCATED ON HARD DRIVE WITH ext4 FILE SYSTEM, NOT NTFS)

3. All done! You just need to go to Kiwix directory (folder) and run (double click) kiwix file to run it.

(Tip)
Your Home folder should be installed on an ext4 file system (by default when you installed Ubuntu), you may extract it there (in a folder on your desktop, for example). Libraries (which are large) you can download on other hard drive.